# OSX, HIDTransaction and IOHIDDeviceSetReport, which one should used?

Tags: macos, usb, hid

Checked from osx website, IOHIDDeviceSetReport is a low-level function to setreport. it has a high level one, HIDTransaction, including HIDQueue. 
Which one should i use? I do not see many examples using IOHIDDeviceSetReport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what you need to do.

- If you need to change a HID Value (read: the value of a HID Element), just use the [HID Value functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/HID/new_api_10_5/tn2187.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000970-CH214-SW8)
- If you need to change many such values at the same time, use the
  [HID Transaction functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/HID/new_api_10_5/tn2187.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000970-CH214-SW7)
- If you know how raw data is packed in the HID output report, and you need to send that raw data to the HID device, use [IOHIDDeviceSetReport](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/HID/new_api_10_5/tn2187.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000970-CH214-SW81)